# How to increase width of a wpf expander content programmatically?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a basic expander that contains one grid and one expander.
How can i modify width of expander content programmatically? I've searched a lot 
but i didn't find anything usefull.
Here is my code:

```
 <Expander Header="Test" ExpandDirection="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Background="LightBlue" Collapsed="VerticalExpander_OnCollapsed" Expanded="VerticalExpander_OnExpanded">

    <Grid x:Name="Grid">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit"/>
            <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="5" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext" ResizeDirection="Columns"/>
        </Grid>
```

```
   private void VerticalExpander_OnExpanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Grid.ColumnDefinitions[0].Width = new GridLength(300, GridUnitType.Pixel);
        this.Grid.ColumnDefinitions[2].Width = new GridLength(300, GridUnitType.Pixel);
    }

    private void VerticalExpander_OnCollapsed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Result:
[image]

When i expand i want to change content width programmatically.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Set the `Width` property of the `Grid`? Or what do you mean?

Comment: i want to increase the content width and also move the gridSplitter with content.It's like i move the grid splitter and content width is already adjusted. Maybe a question that can solve this is: How can i set position of gridsplitter? Maybe if i'm changing the position of gridSplitter content will be adjusted

Comment: Set the `Width` of the first `ColumnDefinition`?

Comment: this.Grid.ColumnDefinitions[0].Width = new GridLength(300, GridUnitType.Pixel);
I tried with this on VerticalExpander_OnExpanded method but gridSpliiter remains on the same position

Comment: You should set the `Width` of `this.Grid.ColumnDefinitions[2]` if you want the splitter to move.

Comment: this.Grid.ColumnDefinitions[0].Width = new GridLength(300, GridUnitType.Pixel);
 this.Grid.ColumnDefinitions[2].Width = new GridLength(300, GridUnitType.Pixel);
Splitter Remains in the same position

Comment: If you only increase the width of the third column, it should move. Please provide a repo of your issue if you need any further help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210436/discussion-between-marian-and-mm8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to to move the `GridSplitter` to the left, you could increase the `Width` of the third column, e.g.:

```
this.Grid.ColumnDefinitions[2].Width = new GridLength(300, GridUnitType.Pixel);
```